# Unable to see signer certificate alias in drop down list for aliases created in Websphere 8.5

Tags: ssl, certificate, websphere, signer

In Websphere 8.5  I am trying to install a signer certificate in the **NodeDefaultTrustStore** using the Admin Console. I am also trying to create a dynamic outbound endpoint which will use this signer certificate when making secured outbound connections. In order  to test this I created a signer certificate for play.google.com by clicking **'Retrieve from port'** button under

**SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates**

and entering details to get the certificate from the play.google.com.  I am able to see the certificate  getting created with an alias play.google.com but when I try to create a **'Dynamic outbound endpoint'** under

**SSL certificate and key management > Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configurations**

and click the button **'Get certificate aliases'** for SSL configuration **'NodeDefaultSSLSettings'** I do not see any alias come up in the drop down list with the name 'play.google.com' which I just created. I am also saving everything to the master configuration and have restarted the server number of times to see the changes take effect. I am new to Websphere and will appreciate if anyone could help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificates aliases which you see are "Certificate alias in key store" are for the personal certificates in NodeDefaultKeyStore. You will not see the aliases for signer certificates from NodeDefaultTrustStore in the list. This is as designed, you can have multiple signer certtifcates in the TrustStore. But you need to select an alias to use a specific personal certificate if there are multiple personal certificates in KeySotre.